# Jenkins API: User.hasPermission always returns true

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing my first plugin for Jenkins that will add some additional permissions to Jenkins' matrix based security authorization.

I'm developing the plugin in NetBeans 8.1. The plugin can build and deploy to Jenkins 1.625.3 and I can see my permission show up in the matrix table.

The plugin has a class that extends the `RunListener<AbstractBuild>` extension point. I override the `setUpEnvironment` method and in this method I'm trying to see if the user that caused the build has my new permissions.

Unfortunately, every time I call `User.get(username).hasPermission(permission)`, the result is true. I've simplified the testing by creating two users:

1. adminuser: has the Administer permission
2. devuser: currently just have overall read and no other checkboxes checked.

If I put a debug break in my `setUpEnvironment` method, and add the following watch, the result is true:

```java
User.get("devuser").hasPermission(hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
```

Intuitively, I look at the code above and think `hasPermission` is based on the `User` returned by the `get` method. However, I'm starting to suspect that it doesn't matter that `hasPermission` is called on the user object, the security principle is some system user with uber access.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

#### Matrix Screenshot

[image: Matrix Screenshot]

#### Debug Watches

[image: Debug Watches]

Comment: This one is tricky. I browsed through the code of [[User](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/User.java)|[ACL|SidACL|SparseACL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/security)].[_]hasPermission() but couldn't find out anything. Can you track down in which of these `true` is set/returned actually?

Comment: I tried it with a _Build - Execute system Groovy script_ and I can confirm this behaviour (in v1.656). Also with _Anonymous_ who hasn't assigned any permission here.

Comment: There's [no (known) bug concerning _haspermission_ describing this behaviour](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1837?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20text%20~%20%22haspermission%22). I'd create an issue for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with is that `User.hasPermission(Permission p)` calls `ACL.hasPermission(Permission p)` which in fact runs:

```java
return hasPermission(Jenkins.getAuthentication(),p);
```

Therefore permissions are not checked for loaded `User` but for current `User` used to execute this code.

If you run below code from **Script Console**:

```
println instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().
        hasPermission("devuser", hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
println instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.get("devuser")).
        hasPermission(User.get("devuser").impersonate(), hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
println instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.get("devuser")).
        hasPermission(User.get("devuser").impersonate(), hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
println instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.get("devuser")).
        hasPermission(hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
println instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.current()).
        hasPermission(hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
```

it will return:

```
false
false
false
true
true
```

---

As a "**workaround**" try to obtain authorization strategy directly from `Jenkins` object and execute `hasPermission(...)` method from it:

```groovy
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().hasPermission("devuser", Jenkins.ADMINISTER)
```

Comment: He **is** using [`hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Hudson.html#fields_inherited_from_class_jenkins.model.Jenkins) which is inherited from `jenkins.model.Jenkins`.

Comment: @GeroldBroser you're 100% right. I've refined my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help everyone! I got it working by using the `instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.get("devuser")).
        hasPermission(User.get("devuser").impersonate(), hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)`